# Pandas - How to get value from a specific column by finding value on that row in a different column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get a value from a specific column that is on a same row as a highest value in a different column. Anyone can help?

I have tried it as df["Column1"][df["Column2].max()], it gives back only the value from Column2 as an Error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `idxmax` as the simple example below shows. This provides the index position of the max in one column which can be used to access that row and so the value in another column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                    'col2' : [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
                    })

max_col2 = df['col2'][df['col1'].idxmax()]

print(max_col2)
```

gives:

```
14
```

alternatively (but more complicated)to use **max()** you could use:

```
max_col2 = df['col2'][df['col1'] == df['col1'].max()].values[0]
```

which also gives

```
14
```